# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'serialize' - after attempting to execute a plan

Tags: ros, moveit, load, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I'm using moveit's move_group_interface in Python 3 and ROS Noetic. I'm trying to save a plan (trajectory), then load it and execute.

```
    pose_goal = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
    pose_goal.orientation.x = 0
    pose_goal.orientation.y = 0.7071068
    pose_goal.orientation.z = 0
    pose_goal.orientation.w = 0.7071068
    pose_goal.position.x = x
    pose_goal.position.y = y
    pose_goal.position.z = z

    self.move_group.set_pose_target(pose_goal)
    plan = self.move_group.plan()

    file_path =  'plan.yaml'
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file_save:
            yaml.dump(plan, file_save, default_flow_style=True)

    with open(file_path, 'r') as file_open:
            loaded_plan = yaml.load(file_open)
    self.move_group.execute(loaded_plan)
```

The execute line outputs:

```
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'serialize'
```

Even if I replace the execute(loaded_plan ) with execute(plan) it still outputs the same error which leads me to believe the error is not in the saving/loading part.

Robot: Universal Robot 5 (UR5)
Interface: moveit/move_group_interface in Pyhon

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377150/attributeerror:-%27tuple%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27serialize%27---after-attempting-to-execute-a-plan/) by [meowatthemoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/73807/meowatthemoon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The return value of `move_group.plan()` may be `yaml.dump(..)`-able, but the `yaml.load(..)`-ed version of that is just a `dict`, not an actual `Plan` instance.

`move_group.execute(..)` does not take a `dict`, hence the error message when it tries to use whatever you're passing it as a `Plan`.

From the [move_group.py documentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/moveit_commander/html/move__group_8py_source.html#l00604):

```
 def plan(self, joints=None):
     """Return a tuple of the motion planning results such as
     (success flag : boolean, trajectory message : RobotTrajectory,
      planning time : float, error code : MoveitErrorCodes)"""
     if type(joints) is JointState:
         self.set_joint_value_target(joints)

     elif type(joints) is Pose:
         self.set_pose_target(joints)

     elif joints is not None:
         try:
             self.set_joint_value_target(self.get_remembered_joint_values()[joints])
         except MoveItCommanderException:
             self.set_joint_value_target(joints)

     (error_code_msg, trajectory_msg, planning_time) = self._g.plan()

     error_code = MoveItErrorCodes()
     error_code.deserialize(error_code_msg)
     plan = RobotTrajectory()
     return (
         error_code.val == MoveItErrorCodes.SUCCESS,
         plan.deserialize(trajectory_msg),
         planning_time,
         error_code,
     )
```

Note how the return value is a tuple, with at least one element being a `RobotTrajectory` instance.

You *might* be able to transform one of the members of the `dict` you `yaml.load(..)` into a `RobotTrajectory` instance again using something like [rospy_message_converter](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_message_converter), but no guarantees.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3